# How to print non duplicated rows based on a field with AWK?

Tags: unix, awk

I wish to print the non duplicated rows based on the 1st field using AWK. Could anyone please kindly help?

Thanks

```
    Input 

    1 28324 2077 2 1
    1 24682 2088 1 0
    1 25399 2074 1 0
    2 28925 1582 2 1
    3 30254 1450 1 0
    4 25552 1131 1 1
    4 31033 1134 1 0
    5 29230 1522 2 0


    Desired Output 
    2 28925 1582 2 1
    3 30254 1450 1 0
    5 29230 1522 2 0
```

Comment: You mean duplicated by the first column. Is it always sorted?

Comment: Yes, but should that depend on whether it is sorted?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
(count[$1]++ < 1) { data[$1] = $0; }
END               { for (x in data) if (count[x] == 1) print data[x]; }
'
```

If the output should be sorted on the first column, pipe it through `sort -nk1`.

Comment: You need to post-increment the array element. I get no output with your code as it is.

Comment: Could you deal with an overflow?

Comment: @belisarius: I don't, I assume I never have more than 2^wordsize records of the same type. In fact, I handle such large datasets using MongoDB, not a single text file and awk.

Comment: @larsmans Many years ago I converted a huge scripts library for a bank using awk for a migration. I vaguely remember having to cope with overflows in arrays ... but I don't remember how I did it :(

Comment: @belisarius, @Dennis Williamson's answer avoids the issue altogether.

Comment: Sometimes it's a memory issue on embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is sorted, you can use this which doesn't accumulate a potentially large array.

```
awk '
    $1 != prev { if (count == 1) print line; count = 0 }
               { prev=$1; line = $0; ++count }
           END { if (count == 1) print }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

For fixed number of characters in the first column and *uniq* implementation that supports *-w* option:

```
sort infile|uniq -uw1
```